# Data annotations extensions validators: Is .c0m a valid TLD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I downloaded Data Annotations Extensions for .NET from [Data annotations extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) for use to validate user input in an C#/ASP.NET MVC application. The library came with high commendations from the developer community, including those from Stack Overflow.

One of the inputs I am validating is email. The data annotations extensions are treating an email address like `noreply@user.c0m` as valid - note the `0` in `.c0m`. I have been reading up on the validity of a TLD containing a numeric character but I am coming across conflicting information.

Some internet resources suggest that `.c0m` is a valid TLD while others suggest its not. Others suggest that ICANN might pull (or might have pulled) the plug on them. I would like to get an opinion on the validity or otherwise of such a TLD. Should an email address like `noreply@user.c0m` be considered valid or should I just ditch the Data Annotations Extensions?

Comment: As a sidenote, just take a look at [the sample of valid e-mail addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses) according to RFC. My opinion is to go easy on e-mail validation, 'cause you effectively can't do it - save for sending a mail to which the user has to reply, which is a pain (and the reason for many 5-minute mailbox services). But I digress from the main question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digits are valid in the TLD part.

See the complete list of TLDs here: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt Most Unicode TLDs have digits in them.

Comment: So, going by that list where we have XN--0ZWM56D and XN--11B5BS3A9AJ6G, does it mean that 0ZWM56D are valid 11B5BS3A9AJ6G TLDs?

Comment: No, `XN--0ZWM56D` as a whole is a valid TLD. Some e-mail clients might be able to represent such domain name using the Unicode characters, but this form is what is used underneath because most of the infrastructure only supports ASCII.